# How to auth in instagram with cookies?

Tags: ios, nsstring, instagram, access-token

So I have my code for auth instagram. Token already gives but not work and show message "`You must to switch cookies`". What I must to do? Thanks for answer.

Now i try to take token from instagram:

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://instagram.com"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
NSData *urlData;
NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
NSError *errors;
urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&errors];

NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"csrf_token\":\"(.*)," options:0 error:NULL];
NSString *token = string;
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:token options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [token length])];


NSString *str = [[token substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"}"
                                     withString:@""];

NSLog(@"%@", str);

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"csrfmiddlewaretoken=%@&username=%@&password=%@", str, @"nnn", @"nnnpass"];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://instagram.com/accounts/login/"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&errors];

NSString *string2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", string2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *cookieProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  @"", NSHTTPCookieDomain,
                                  @"\\", NSHTTPCookiePath,
                                  @"csrftoken", NSHTTPCookieName,
                                  @"2dfdbaaeae7752882d792e49d79c0048", NSHTTPCookieValue,
                                  nil];
NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:cookieProperties];
NSArray* cookieArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: cookie, nil];
NSDictionary * headers = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:cookieArray];
```

Add in POST Request:
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];

Comment: Oh really amazing code! I ll try this an few minutes

Comment: @VladIvchenko I was trying to use this code can you please tell me how to get the cookies from the server instead of add it by myself?

Comment: Anybody know how to add the headers to the request in swift?